# Telegram bot get chat informations python

Tags: url, telegram, telegram-bot

about telegram bots , how can I get json information from a special chat (not all chats , by chat ID) by url like getupdates (`https://api.telegram.org/bot/getupdates`) .

because I get little information from getupdates I want to know some info like member IDs and messages IDs etc. in each group and chats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to filter updates specifically by chat id (API **does not** permit that), if not onto your own code, however, you could still filter updates by their type.

Here's an example on how to filter callback queries and messages only:

```
api.telegram.org/bot{token}/getUpdates?allowed_updates=["callback_query","message"]
```

Note: as written on [BotApi Documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates), even if you pass `allowed_updates` parameter on `getUpdates`, only new received updates will be filtered following filters:

> Please note that this parameter doesn't affect updates created before
> the call to the getUpdates, so unwanted updates may be received for a
> short period of time.

All possible update types are listed here: [core.telegram.org/bots/api#update](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update)

Comment: thanks a lot for helping . I got it how can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the **ID** of the chat, you can use these methods:

- [getChat](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchat) - to get up to date info about the chat.

  - returns [Chat](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chat) object on success
- [getChatAdministrators](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatadministrators) - to get a list of admins in a chat.

  - returns an **Array** of [ChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmember) on success.
- [getChatMembersCount](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmemberscount) - to get the number of members in a chat.

  - returns `Int`  on success
- [getChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember) - to get information about a member of a chat.

  - returns [ChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmember) on success.

All these methods require the `chat_id` parameter, which can be **Integer** or **String** type. You can specify chat or channel username like `@channelusername`

Example request:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<API_TOKEN>/getChat?chat_id=<CHAT_ID>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for helping . I got it how can I do this.

Comment: @SyHoMadara glad to hear that. Don't forget to upvote the answer if found it useful :)